# Jewish wisdom on how to remain calm under stressful situations

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, tanach

What do the scriptures say on how to  calm oneself down when one is faced with exiting his comfort zone? As long as I can remember, I've always became quite nervous with uncomfortable feelings whenever it was time to leave my comfort zone behind and jump into the cold. Unfortunately it affects my thinking process, my appetite, and my behaviours in general. I hate being a nervous wreck and I'd rather be calm when the storm hits.

What advice can Jewish sources give me on that particular issue?

Comment: Do you want Jewish sources or specifically scripture? (I’d go with the former)

Comment: How early of Jewish sources are you looking for?

Comment: Jewish sources in general in that case, I guess. Anything that can help me to get my 'stuff' together and stop acting up. The feeling of nervousness truly does stupid things with my mind and my thought process is heavily disturbed, amongst other things. As a human being, it is only natural to feel some discomfort when leaving the comfort behind. But I want to ease those rather negative feelings of anxiety and nervousness. So, it doesn't matter how old that source might, or where it is written. @Dr. Shmuel and DonielF

Comment: Have you heard of Nachum Ish Gamzu and גם זו לטובה?

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel : No, I haven't yet. Though I do know that to some extent primitive physical exercise and physical exhaustion to some degree can lessen these 'feelings'. I need to get the initial steam off before I can sit calmly on the desk and read without my thoughts dwelling on the events that are to happen in the near future. So, keep the suggestions going, I will take a look once I'm back from the gym.

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel 'gam zu le-tovah' - there is no doubt in my mind that it holds the utter truth. Judaism taught me that everything that happens in ones life, is for the best. But still, I feel like I 'underperform' when I'm under those stressful feelings. Maybe my emunah is not deep enough. But in those immediate moments where everything 'is shaken to the core', it's a bit difficult to internalize the phrase.

Comment: As far as preemption by affirmation goes, there are some little snippets that are commonly tacked on to the end of the _amida_ and therefore repeated throughout the day every day by many people that encourage certain habits of calmness ([e.g.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Weekday_Shacharit%2C_Amidah)).

Answer (score 4):

I can say from experience to say Tehillim 23 and meditate on the meaning of the words which is in essence a personal experience of Dovid Hamelech when he was on the run outside his "comfort zone" how thinking About Hashem how really every human is helpless without His constant presence and guidance. Throughout the generations we have survived through his embrace G-d is constantly with us and everything He orchestrates will be Good for us.

> ה' רֹעִי לֹא אֶחְסָר בִּנְאוֹת דֶּשֶׁא יַרְבִּיצֵנִי עַל מֵי מְנֻחוֹת יְנַהֲלֵנִי נַפְשִׁי יְשׁוֹבֵב יַנְחֵנִי בְמַעְגְּלֵי צֶדֶק לְמַעַן שְׁמוֹ גַּם כִּי אֵלֵךְ בְּגֵיא צַלְמָוֶת לֹא אִירָא רָע כִּי אַתָּה עִמָּדִי שִׁבְטְךָ וּמִשְׁעַנְתֶּךָ הֵמָּה יְנַחֲמֻנִי
>   The LORD is my shepherd; I lack nothing.He makes me lie down in green pastures; He leads me to water in places of peace; He reinvigorates my life; He guides me in right paths as befits His name.Though I walk through a valley of deepest darkness, I fear no harm, for You are with me; Your rod and Your staff—they comfort me.

Comment: A similiar mindset helped me through the travelling experience with my gentile father. Everything is so much easier if you conciously live with hashem